# Error Checking on Columns in Data File Using If and While Loop

Tags: r

I am using a While loop and If Statement to produce text on a graph.

I am trying to use the If Statement as an error checking. If there is no data in the column Lon and Lat skip this and move on to the next row.

In my data table shown there are no values in the Lat and Lon columns which is why they appear as NA as shown below:

```
  myData3[1:7,]
  ISO3V10              Country No.of.Documents Lat Lon
1     AGO               Angola               0  NA  NA
2     ALB              Albania               0  NA  NA
3     ARE United Arab Emirates               0  NA  NA
4     ARG            Argentina               7  NA  NA
5     ARM              Armenia               0  NA  NA
6     AUS            Australia              96 151 -34
7     AUT              Austria              28  NA  NA
```

The code I have written so far is below:

```
 myData3 <- read.delim(file="C:\\Documents\\RScriptAnalysis\\noofpublications3.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
 data = 0
 n = 0
 while(data < 100){
 if (myData3["Lat", 0] & myData3["Lon", 0])
   {
   data = data +1
   n = n +1
   }
else {
  text(myData3[n,"Lat"],myData3[n,"Lon"],myData3[n,"No.of.Documents"],adj=0.5)
  n = n +1
  data = data +1
  }
}
```

I get these error messages when I change the code:

```
  Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
 'data' must be of a vector type

  Error in 0 = while (data < 1000) { : 
  invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

I need some help to sort out how to do this error checking and adapting my code to be able to do this!!!

Any further questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Cheers, Jess

Comment: I rolled your edit back to the previous version. If you have a new question, you should ask it as a separate question, rather than editing this one.

Answer (score 3):

It's this line:

```
if (myData3["Lat", 0] & myData3["Lon", 0])
```

You want to see if the `n`th row and Lat/Lon columns of `myData3` are NA.

To access row `n` column `Lat` you do:

```
myData3[n,'Lat']
```

or (for data frames):

```
myData3$Lat[n]
```

To test whether something is NA (data missing), use `is.na` (see `?is.na`).

So:

```
if ( is.na(myData$Lat[n]) && is.na(myData$Lon[n]) )
```

should work. (Note the `&&` which is the 'and' operator/logical shortcut. the `&` version compares (for example) vectors *element-wise*, whereby `c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) & c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)` is `c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)` -- it doesn't make sense to use it on scalars).

---

The above will fix your problem, but further notes to your code: R is a *vectorised* language, meaning a lot of the time instead of doing a loop you can pretend your value is a scalar and use the same code.

For example, `x + 5` where `x` is a vector will add `5` to *each element* of `x`, meaning you don't have to write a loop doing `x[i] + 5` for each `i` going from 1 to `length(x)`.

In the above, you can just generate a vector of row numbers in `myData3` where Lat and Lon are not na like so:

```
idx = !is.na(myData3$Lat) & !is.na(myData3$Lon)
```

Here, `idx` will be a vector of TRUE and FALSE  that is as long as the number of rows in `myData3` (note I used `&` here instead of `&&` to get an element-wise and).
`idx` will be `TRUE` where Lat and Lon are *both* not NA, and `FALSE` otherwise.

Then to plot, you can just feed the valid rows in to `text` all at once like so:

```
text(myData3$Lat[idx],myData3$Lon[idx],myData3$No.of.Documents[idx],adj=0.5)
```

This is because most R functions are vectorised, so you can feed in a whole vector and it will have the effect of looping over each element.

Note that `myData3$Lat[idx]` picks out those rows of `myData3$Lat` where `idx` is TRUE, i.e. those rows where both Lat and Lon exist.

If this is your first time with a vectorised language (like R and Matlab) don't worry, you'll eventually get the hang of it. It's fun!